# Action of the translation operator on a ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, hilbert-space

I am trying to show that:

\begin{align}
\exp\left[-ia \bf{p}/ \hbar \right]\exp\left[ib\bf{q}/\hbar \right]|q\rangle &= \exp\left[ib q/\hbar \right] \exp\left[-ia \bf{p} /\hbar\right] |q\rangle \\&= \exp\left[ibq/\hbar \right]|q+a\rangle 
\end{align}

where $\bf{p}$ and $\bf{q}$ are the canonical operators.

I don't know how to prove the last equality:

$$\exp\left[-i\bf{p}/\hbar\right]|q\rangle = |q+a\rangle.$$

Comment: Have you looked at the [relevant wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wiki entry is useful but I think a simpler way might be to ask: what is the eigenvalue of $\textbf{q}$ for the state $\exp[-i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle$?

Start with
\begin{align}
\textbf{q}\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle&=
\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]
\left[\exp[i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar]\textbf{q}
\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\right] \vert q\rangle \tag{1}
\end{align}
and unpack $\exp[i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar]\textbf{q}
\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]$ using the series expansion:
\begin{align}
\exp[i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar]\textbf{q}
\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]&\approx
\left[1+i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar\right]\textbf{q}
\left[1-i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar\right]\, ,\\
&=\textbf{q}+i\alpha [\textbf{p},\textbf{q}]/\hbar+\ldots\, ,\tag{2}\\
&= \textbf{q}+\alpha\hat 1\, .  \tag{3}
\end{align} 
Note that although (3) is obtained through a series it is *exact* since the commutator $[\textbf{p},\textbf{q}]$ commutes with $\textbf{p}$.  In other words, if you continue (2) beyond the first term you will still get (3).  Now insert (3) in (1) gives
\begin{align}
\textbf{q}\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle &=
\exp [-i\alpha \textbf{p}/\hbar](q+\alpha)\vert q\rangle\, ,\\
&=(q+\alpha)\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle\, . \tag{4}
\end{align}
since $\vert q\rangle$ is an eigenket of $\textbf{q}$ with eigenvalue $q$.  (4) shows that $\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle$ is an eigenket of $\textbf{q}$ with eigenvalue $q+\alpha$, which identifies $\exp[-i\alpha\textbf{p}/\hbar]\vert q\rangle$ as $\vert q+\alpha\rangle$.